# Statistics in python: MFB and MFE

Tags: python, statistics

I have been requested in work to compute MFB and MFE. In the attached image the formulas are cited, and below is the code I used.

```
MFB=(2*np.nansum((MODEL-MEAS)))/(N*np.nansum(np.absolute(MODEL+MEAS)))
MFE=(2*np.nansum(np.absolute(MODEL-MEAS)))/(N*np.nansum(np.absolute(MODEL+MEAS)))
```

When I showed my result, I was told that the values were very low. [image]

Comment: You have `MODELMEAS` there -- is that supposed to be `MODEL-MEAS`?  And why did you split the sum into two sums?  If the values can be negative, I don't think that's a safe operation.  Are there NANs in your data?

Comment: your implementation of the formula looks incorrect.

Comment: Yes, you are right  I edited it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the literal translation:

```
MFB=2/N*np.nansum((MODEL-MEAS)/(MODEL+MEAS))
MFE=2/N*np.nansum(np.absolute((MODEL-MEAS)/(MODEL+MEAS)))
```

Comment: but isn't it the summation `(M1-O1)/(M1+O1) + (M2-O2)/(M2+O2) + (M3-O3)/(M3+O3).. + ..+ (MN-ON)/(MN+ON)` ?

Comment: That's exactly what this should be doing -- elementwise operations.  Am I wrong?

Comment: You are right @Tim.. I guess `MODEL` and `MEAS` should be `np.arrays` with `MODEL = [M1, M2,..]` and `MEAS = [O1, O2..]`